# Django admin limit rights

Tags: python, django, admin

In my Django project I have the models `Project`, `Person`, `Task` and `Info`.

Thing is, however, that the Project is the parent model. Person, Task and Info belongs to the Project.

If I add a Person, Task or Info I have to choose the Project (ForeignKey) it belongs to.

My problem: Those projects are independent and I have different project managers. My goal is that in the admin interface the project manager of project A for example can only add a Person to HIS project, same with Info and Task.

I don't want that the project manger of project A can see/edit/add/delete things of project B. Unfortunately, I could not find options in the Django admin that meets my requirements.

If the project manager logs in he should only see instances that belongs to his project, nothing else.

How would you solve that issue?

Comment: You basically want object level permissions. And that's not included in the default admin to handle it, you'd have to modify quite a bit.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset This might be of help

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, I suppose your model structure looks like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Person(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    ...
```

In your `admin.py` you can perform various modifications to accomplish your goal

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # other code

    # this function will list persons
    # only whose project has current user as project manager
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(project__manager__user=request.user)

    # this function will list the projects in dropdowns
    # who has current user as project manager
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            context['adminform'].form.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(manager__user=request.user)
        return super(PersonAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)

    # this function is used for edit permission
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if not obj:
        return True 
    return obj.project.manager.user == request.user or request.user.is_superuser

    # this function is used for delete permission
    def has_delete_permssion(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return True
        return obj.project.manager.user == request.user or request.user.is_superuser
```

#### Similar approach can be used for other models in admin